# Mail marketer - avoid google image proxy to detect devices

Tags: email

I'm trying to detect the devices that open my newsletter parsing the user-agent that request my 1x1 tracking image. The problem is that Gmail save all of the images in his storage and the user agent is always "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)", this if the opener is from the gmail app and when is from the desktop interface.

Now the question is, there's a way to tell Google avoiding to save the image in the newsletter? Maybe there's a custom header in the mail?

Or maybe there are other solutions for detecting the tipology of the devices that open newsletter from gmail official interface?
Thanks to all.

Yuri

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I'm aware of is the one provided by [ContactMonkey](http://www.contactmonkey.com/), but it's a proprietary system so I'm not sure of how it works. They have a free plan so you can test out their software and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I've tried but it same that also [ContactMonkey](http://www.contactmonkey.com/) have this problem.